# How does look like an open set in one point compactification?

Tags: general-topology

How does look like an open set in one point compactification?
$X$ is that space and $Y$ is its one point compactification.
Is it:

$U$ open in $Y$ if it is open in $X$ or if $U=Y\backslash C$, for some compact space $C$ in $X$?

Comment: $C$ is a compact and _closed_ set in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Almost. If we consider $X \subset Y$, as you seem to do, then

$U$ is open in $Y$ iff ($U \subseteq X$ and $U$ open in $X$) or ($U = Y \setminus C$ where $C$ is compact and closed in $X$).

The closedness is redundant if we assume $X$ is already Hausdorff to begin with.